# How to filter this pandas dataframe by row’s value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

This is my pandas dataframe

```
print(df)

Name       Sale Value
ADAMSAE    1475000
BAKERDE    1412000
CLARKAE    1480450
DAVISDE    1483700
EVANSAE    1285000
```

Can anyone tell me how can I filter the row by its Name columns last two character of the string like this---**ADAMSAE BAKERDE**  by **AE DE**

*Expected dataframe------*

```
print(AE_df)
Name       Sale Value
ADAMSAE    1475000
CLARKAE    1480450
EVANSAE    1285000
```

and

```
print(DE_df)
Name       Sale Value
BAKERDE    1412000
DAVISDE    1483700
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df['Name'].str[-2:]`.

output:

```
0    AE
1    DE
2    AE
3    DE
4    AE
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

To make groups automatically:

```
d = dict(list(df.groupby(df['Name'].str[-2:])))
```

output:

```
{'AE':       Name  Sale Value
 0  ADAMSAE     1475000
 2  CLARKAE     1480450
 4  EVANSAE     1285000,
 'DE':       Name  Sale Value
 1  BAKERDE     1412000
 3  DAVISDE     1483700}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [endswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html), like:

```
df[df.Name.str.endswith('AE')]
```